# if more than 1 match, do not return 'unknown'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I composed a monster query. I'm certain that it can be optimized, and I would more than appreciate any comments/guidance on the query itself; however, I have a specific question:

The data I am returning is sometimes duplicated on multiple columns:

```
+-------+------+----------+------+-------+--------+----------+-------+------+
| first | last |  deaID   | cert | count |  npi   | clientid | month | year |
+-------+------+----------+------+-------+--------+----------+-------+------+
| Alex  | Jue  | UNKNOWN  | MD   |    11 | 123123 |   102889 |     7 | 2012 |
| Alex  | Jue  | BJ123123 | MD   |    11 | 123123 |   102889 |     7 | 2012 |
+-------+------+----------+------+-------+--------+----------+-------+------+
```

as you can see all of the fields are equal except for `deaID`

in this case, I would like to only return:

```
+------+-----+----------+----+----+--------+--------+---+------+
|      |     |          |    |    |        |        |   |      |
+------+-----+----------+----+----+--------+--------+---+------+
| Alex | Jue | BJ123123 | MD | 11 | 123123 | 102889 | 7 | 2012 |
+------+-----+----------+----+----+--------+--------+---+------+
```

however, if there are no duplicates:

```
+-------+------+---------+------+-------+--------+----------+-------+------+
| first | last |  deaID  | cert | count |  npi   | clientid | month | year |
+-------+------+---------+------+-------+--------+----------+-------+------+
| Alex  | Jue  | UNKNOWN | MD   |    11 | 123123 |   102889 |     7 | 2012 |
+-------+------+---------+------+-------+--------+----------+-------+------+
```

then i would like to keep it!

**summary**
if there are duplicates remove all records with `'deaID=unknown'`; however, if there is only 1 match then return that match

**question**
how do i return `unknown` records IFF there is 1 match?

here is the monster query in case anybody is interested :)

```
with ctebiggie  as (

select distinct
p.[IMS_PRESCRIBER_ID],
p.PHYSICIAN_NPI as MLISNPI,
a.CLIENT_ID,
p.MLIS_FIRSTNAME,
p.MLIS_LASTNAME,
p_address.IMS_DEA_NBR,
p.IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR,
p.IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR_src,
p.IMS_CERTIFICATION_CODE,
datepart(mm,a.RECEIVED_DATE) as [Month],
datepart(yyyy,a.RECEIVED_DATE) as [Year]

from

MILLENNIUM_DW_dev..D_PHYSICIAN p
left outer join
MILLENNIUM_DW_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY a
on a.REQUESTOR_NPI=p.PHYSICIAN_NPI
left outer join MILLENNIUM_DW_dev..D_PHYSICIAN_ADDRESS p_address
on p.PHYSICIAN_NPI=p_address.PHYSICIAN_NPI

where 
a.RECEIVED_DATE is not null
--and p.IMS_PRESCRIBER_ID is not null
--and p_address.IMS_DEA_NBR !='UNKNOWN'
and p.REC_ACTIVE_FLG=1
and p_address.REC_ACTIVE_FLG=1
and DATEPART(yyyy,received_date)=2012
  and DATEPART(mm,received_date)=7


group by 
p.[IMS_PRESCRIBER_ID],
p.PHYSICIAN_NPI,
p.IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR,
p.MLIS_FIRSTNAME,
p.MLIS_LASTNAME,
p_address.IMS_DEA_NBR,
p.IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR,
p.IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR_src,
p.IMS_CERTIFICATION_CODE,
datepart(mm,a.RECEIVED_DATE),
datepart(yyyy,a.RECEIVED_DATE),
a.CLIENT_ID

)
,
ctecount as 
(select
 COUNT (Distinct f.ACCESSION_ID) [count],
 f.REQUESTOR_NPI,f.CLIENT_ID,
 datepart(mm,f.RECEIVED_DATE) mm,
datepart(yyyy,f.RECEIVED_DATE)yyyy
from MILLENNIUM_DW_dev..F_ACCESSION_DAILY f

where 
 f.CLIENT_ID not in (select * from SalesDWH..TestPractices)

 and DATEPART(yyyy,f.received_date)=2012
  and DATEPART(mm,f.received_date)=7


group by f.REQUESTOR_NPI,
f.CLIENT_ID,
datepart(mm,f.RECEIVED_DATE),
datepart(yyyy,f.RECEIVED_DATE)
)

select ctebiggie.*,c.* from
ctebiggie
full outer join
ctecount c
on c.REQUESTOR_NPI=ctebiggie.MLISNPI
and c.mm=ctebiggie.[Month]
and c.yyyy=ctebiggie.[Year]
and c.CLIENT_ID=ctebiggie.CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: I think to answer your question you will need to provide the query, or the part that pulls this information.

Comment: @ShawnMelton thank you very much for pointing that out. i forgot to include it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this helps or not

```
select distinct main.col1,main.col2  ,
       isnull(( select col3 from table1 where table1.col1=main.col1
       and table1.col2=main.col2 and col3 <>'UNKNOWN'),'UNKNOWN')
from   table1 main
```

[Sample in Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdae0/1/0)

or fair version of yours will be

```
SELECT distinct first,
       last,
       cert,
       count,
       npi,
       clientid,
       month,
       year,
      isnull(
      select top 1 dealid from table1 intable where 
      intable.first=maintable.first and
      intable.last=maintable.last and
      intable.cert=maintable.cert and
      intable.npi=maintable.npi and
      intable.clientid=outtable.clientid and
      intable.month=outtable.month and
      intable.year=outtable.year
      where dealid<>'UNKNOWN'),'UNKNOWN') as dealId
FROM  table1 maintable
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. can you please tell me how does this eliminate duplicates? can youexplain please?

Comment: this one excludes col3 in my case or DEALID in yours , then do a distinct of all other columns will give you the desired result except this col3 (or DEALID) ,now add the column to select list by querying to the table where that comes from.

Comment: thank you so much this looks amazing. can you please show me how i can apply it to my query?

Comment: im getting this error Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: isnull(( select IMS_DEA_NBR from ctemain where 
ctemain.IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR_src=main.IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR_src and
ctemain.IMS_CERTIFICATION_CODE=main.IMS_CERTIFICATION_CODE and
ctemain.[Month]=main.[Month] and
ctemain.[Year]=main.[Year] and
ctemain.[count]=main.[count] and
ctemain.REQUESTOR_NPI=main.REQUESTOR_NPI and
ctemain.CLIENT_ID2=main.CLIENT_ID2 and
ctemain.mm=main.mm and
ctemain.yyyy =main.yyyy  
and IMS_DEA_NBR <>'UNKNOWN'),'UNKNOWN')  because that can return multiple reocrds

Comment: its probably a problem with the ISNULL statement because it can return multiple records!! thank again so much for looking into this!!

Comment: if you put the results from your monster query to a temporary table where i can remove the duplicates which makes easier

Comment: im so sorry i cannot do that because it is private information

Comment: did that help? I thought you preferred the other one. this was a surprise score for me

Comment: It will not work if we have multiple rows with non unknown values, values which are not unknown. We will only get one row.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the base query, I will assign row_number and count by partition function over this resultset. Then on the outer select, if count is 1 then unknown is selected, else it is not selected.

```
SELECT first,
       last,
       deaID,
       cert,
       count,
       npi,
       clientid,
       month,
       year
  FROM (
         SELECT first,
                last,
                deaID,
                cert,
                count,
                npi,
                clientid,
                month,
                year,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                                     first,last,cert,count,npi,clientid,month,year 
                                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN deaID = 'Unkown' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                                       deaID) AS RowNumberInGroup,
                COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY first,last,cert,count,npi,clientid,month,year)
                    AS CountPerGroup,
                 SUM(CASE WHEN deaID = 'Unkown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                     OVER (PARTITION BY first,last,cert,count,npi,clientid,month,year)
                     AS UnknownCountPerGroup
           FROM BaseQuery
      ) T
 WHERE (T.CountPerGroup = T.UnknownCountPerGroup AND T.RowNumberInGroup = 1) OR T.RowNumberInGroup > T.UnknownCountPerGroup
```

Comment: thanks so much!! can you please tell me if you think tim's query is similar ?

Comment: Please check the updated query, its not similar. it will handle various scenarios like if you have duplicate unknown then only single unknown is return, if you have even one record which is not unknown then all the unknown records are suppressed.

Comment: i've updated my query with what you have provided for me: http://pastebin.com/XZxDDNLr

Comment: i am getting Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 156
Incorrect syntax near 'COUNT'.

Comment: Sorry i missed a , after RowNumberInGroup. I have fixed it now. The query is still untested.

Comment: thank you again. http://pastebin.com/JZzivAfi  it ran! however it is returning A LOT of the null values for          IMS_PRESCRIBER_ID   ,
         MLISNPI  ,
         CLIENT_ID1  ,
         MLIS_FIRSTNAME   ,
         MLIS_LASTNAME   ,
         IMS_DEA_NBR   ,
         IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR   ,
         IMS_PROFESSIONAL_ID_NBR_src   ,
         IMS_CERTIFICATION_CODE   ,
         [Month]   ,
         [Year]   ---however, the COUNT is correct

Comment: Still not able to get the query, can you please show sample records which you this are incorrect ...

Comment: lots of null are because of full outer join, i suspect there is a row which is in count dte but does not have matching row in ctebiggie ... Why do you need full outer join ...

Comment: thank you again so much. you have put me on the right track!! the outer join is because i want to include values even if they do not exist on both sides of the JOIN

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16431/discussion-between-nitin-midha-and--)